# Error with listen gem loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, listen, spring-gem

I wanted to use `spring` gem on my Rails 4.0.2 project.

To get further functionality, I added `listen` gem as well.

Unfortunately, when doing `rails c`, the loader gives the following error:

```
bi@nona:~/ror/prj$ rails c
/home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:224:in 
`block in replace_gem': can't activate listen (~> 1.0), already activated 
listen-2.4.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/watcher/listen.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/watcher.rb:17:in `require_relative'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/watcher.rb:17:in `watch_method='
    from /home/bi/Desktop/my_docs/Inbox/ror/soqqa/config/spring.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/commands.rb:39:in `require'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/commands.rb:39:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/commands.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/server.rb:18:in `require'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/server.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:35:in `block in boot_server'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:34:in `fork'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:34:in `boot_server'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:18:in `call'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:23:in `call'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:23:in `run'
    from /home/bi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/spring-1.0.0/bin/spring:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `load'
    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

By the way, `rails server` runs alright.

I tried to fix the problem -- removed previous version (0.7.3) of listen gem and issued `spring stop`. But it keeps complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, specify the **version** in your *Gemfile* like
`gem 'listen', '~> 1.0'`
then run **bundle install** and it should work.